# JS Async Function Stops Page Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have a single page with a table. On Page load this table will get updated with data. I need something resembling a thread once table is created so that is can be refreshed every few seconds.

At the moment once the data is fetched on ajax call. If i call asyncThread()
the table doesnt load on the page, the UI is hung and stuck in a loop.
How do i prevent the UI hanging when calling the asyncThread() function ?

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'xxxxxxxxx',
                contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
                type: 'GET'
            }).success(function (result) {
                $('#table')
                    .DataTable(
                        {
                            paging: false,
                            "ordering": false,
                            "language": {
                                "decimal": ",",
                                "thousands": "."
                            },
                            searching: false,
                            "scrollCollapse": true,
                            "scrollY": "75vh"
                        });
                asyncThread();
            }).error(function () {

            });
```

.

```
    async function asyncThread() {
        while (true) {
            console.log('loop started');
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('sleep');
            }, (3 * 1000))
        }           

    }
```

Comment: yeah, your while loop is blocking further processing. If you want to do something with poll requests, use a `setInterval`. Javascript only has 1 thread where it can do something, and it will never get outside of your while loop. To me it really seems like you don't get the concept of the javascript language, neither what `async`/`await` is really used for

Comment: i thought when it came across an async function it would process that as a separate task and continue main one.

Comment: No, it wouldn't, I tried to give a more comprehensive answer about potential misconceptions, I hope it gives you a bit more insight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first analyze your `asyncThread` method

```
async function asyncThread() {
    while (true) {
        console.log('loop started');
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('sleep');
        }, (3 * 1000))
    }           

}
```

What you are doing here, shows that you lack the understanding of how the JavaScript engine works:

- JavaScript is single threaded.
- `async` methods return an implicit promise, they don't really run asynchronous per say
- Your while loop will run indefinitely, your setTimeout function will never be executed, as this would only happen when you the JavaScript engine gets time to execute something else (which it can't, as it is stuck in your while loop)

Typically, for these polling requests, you would rely on `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. The first will periodically execute a function until `clearInterval` is called or the page is unloaded, the second will run once unless `clearTimeout` was called before the timeout expires.

`async` denotes that the function will give back a promise, which you could then handle through the promise chain, or from a different `async` method, you could `await` its successful completion

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i think the SetInterval is what am after rather than the async function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have infinite loop `while (true) {...}` which is blocking main thread. I think, what you looking for is

```
function asyncThread() {
    console.log('loop started');
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('sleep');
        asyncThread();
    }, 3000)
}
```